# Child SWF is caching even though browser cache is disabled

Tags: caching, flash, cache-control, browser-cache

I've got a parent SWF that loads in a couple child SWFs. Even though my browser cache is cleared -- it's disabled, in fact -- reloading, or even restarting, the browser doesn't trigger the newest version of the child SWFs to load into the parent SWF. I can even delete the SWF off the FTP server, and it still gives me the last version that was up there.

What's caching the child SWFs, and how do I force them to refresh on my end? I'm not too concerned about the end user, because once the site development is over, the SWF files won't change very often. (They're all loading in XML files that have the cache disabled via PHP cache control and expires headers.)

I'm primarily using Firefox on PC and Mac, but it seems to do the same thing on IE/PC and Safari/Mac. The PC is using my ISP's DNS, and the Mac is using OpenDNS... not sure if that has anything to do with it. The site is hosted on Rackspace Cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be cached by an intermediate proxy, and there's no guarentee flash reads your browser settings. The most direct way to bypass caching at all levels is to add a constantly changing random number to the child movie URL as a parameter, ie:

http://path/to/movie.swf?rand=9823478932